# PostgreSQL jsonb value in WHERE BETWEEN clause

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I've got jsonb field in my database table (a_table) with int value within, say:

```
{
  "abc":{
       "def":{
            "ghk":500
        }
   }
}
```

I'm about to create SELECT with filter by this field ("ghk") using WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE ghk BETWEEN 0 AND 1000;
```

How should i create such a query? Couldn't find good tutorial for jsonb usage so far.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
<strike>I found this solution:</strike>

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE a_field #> '{abc,def,ghk}' BETWEEN '0' AND '10000' ;
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#>` returns a JSONB document which you cannot cast to an `int`. You need the `#>>`  operator which returns a scalar value that can be casted to an integer:

```
select *
from a_table
where (json_col #>> '{abc,def,ghk}')::int between 0 and 1000
```

All JSON operators are documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Using `BETWEEN '0' AND '10000'` is not a good idea because this does a string comparison not a numeric comparison. The value `'2'` does not lie between `'0'` and `'10000'`. That's why you need to cast the returned value to a number to get a correct comparison.

Comment: Many thanks :) I'll check your answer as a solution as soon as possible.